# How do I interface OCaml with iPhone API?

Tags: iphone, interop, ocaml

I'd like to start developing applications for iPhone, but I'd really like to use OCaml rather than Objective-C. After some googling, it seems like this is definitely possible, but I haven't found any code snippets which actually compile.

**Is it possible to write iPhone apps using OCaml? If so, could you provide a snippet demonstrating how to make calls into the Cocoa API from OCaml?**

Comment: Hi Juliet, how did you progress with your OCaml/iOS development? I would be very interested in knowing more, because I would like to do the same thing in a few months. Max

Comment: @Max: hi Max :) Me and a few friends were going were going to form a startup company writing iPhone apps, but they weren't quite committed enough to move a project along from idea to reality. In the end learned, the project died before it ever materialized, but at least I got to fiddle with Obj-C and some platforms I'd never worked with before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of the box, OCaml cannot be used to build IPhone apps. You would have to have OCaml output ARM code rather than x86 code. You would also have to build wrappers for all the IPhone API calls.

Still, these guys are going through the pain to try this.

http://web.yl.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~tosh/ocaml-on-iphone/

My humble recomendation is that you focus on using Obj-C for everything. If
you really want an ML, use it only for the kernel or the interesting portion.
I would find an *ML that code gens to something like C, and then use that result
as a library to the app.

Good luck.

Comment: +1: I was afraid it would be harder than it sounds, but think I can live with objective C... as long as I can figure out a clever macro which solves the upward and downwards funargs problem ;)

Answer (score 13):

We have instructions for building an OCaml-to-iOS cross compiler on our site.  We started with the patches mentioned above, but we found they needed to be modified in several ways to run on a stock iPhone/iPad.  We are selling an iPhone app named Cassino that is entirely written in OCaml (except for thin wrappers to Cocoa Touch).  Wrappers for all of Cocoa Touch would be a big job, but wrappers for a single application aren't so bad.  And coding in OCaml is very pleasant compared to ObjC.

We also just published full sources for a small OCaml iPhone app named *Portland* at our site.  Read more at [psellos.com](http://psellos.com/).

Comment: The instructions were very good and resulted in no errors on building the to-ARM compiler. +1